# How to type these special characters?

Tags: keyboard

how to type there special characters? You can type these on windows by typing ctrl+alt, but it doesn't work here

[image]

Comment: Does <Right Alt> not do this? 

Comment: Use **AltGR** + **Shift** + **1** to obtain `~`.

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu you use ?

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AltGr + Shift + Key to be pressed seems to work. If you get characters other than what's represented on the keyboard your keyboard layout is in Ubuntu may need to be further configured.